# The changed variable value can not be accessed after a change within the function

Tags: javascript, jquery, variables, scope, global-variables

```
        var getFileName = null

        $('#fileInput').change(function() {
            var props = $('#fileInput').prop('files'),
                file = props[0]
            getFileName = "" + file.name
            console.log("inside function: " + getFileName)
        })


        // selected file
        console.log("outside function: " + getFileName);
```

The variable is changing correctly inside the function but i can't get the changed value outside the function. I think i overlook something but i can't fix it at the moment.

Comment: How are you testing it? Because `console.log("outside function: " + getFileName);` will be executed before the `onChange` callback is called. At that time value of `getFileName` is `null` only.

Comment: Pretty sure you need some semicolons at the ends of each statement.

Comment: Yes, I completely overlooked that. Think that will be the problem. Do you have an idea how I can retrieve it after the onChange function.

Comment: Call what you need in `$('...').change(() => {/* Your code */})`

Answer (score 1):

Like mentioned in the comments the lines are not executed in the order they are noted cause of callbacks.

You should probably do this

```
    var getFileName = null; // global variable

    $('#fileInput').change(function() {
        var props = $('#fileInput').prop('files'),
            file = props[0],
            getFileName = "" + file.name
        ;
        console.log("inside function: " + getFileName); // log in callback
        checkOutside();
    })

    function checkOutside(){
        // output global variable after its changed in callback of "change"-event
        console.log("outside function: " + getFileName);
    }
```